# Automatically number rows in Excel according the dates in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Automatically adding serial numbers in Excel is easy, but I would like to know if there is an easier way to add serial numbers only columns near new dates.
I simple works, want to add serial numbers to each days, without any counting duplicates.
Each date should be counted only once.

I am only able to achieve the following.

[image: What I am getting, which wont work for my needs]

But I would like to get the following results, just by dragging from the top column.

[image: What I need, numbering according to new dates in column B]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the *No.* header is in `A1`, in `A2`:

`=IF(B2<>B1,MAX(A$1:A1)+1,"")`

and copied down.

Comment: This one will only work if the dates are arranged in order though right? If a duplicate date ends up out of order in the list, if will be counted again.

Comment: Yes, it will only work if dates are arranged in increasing order.

Answer (score 1):

or may be it can help too

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)>1,"",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```